# How do I rebuild an array without null elements?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, grep

I am trying to create a new array of strings without null elements from an array of strings with null elements.

**Code**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
inlist=(a b c d)  # inlist to be processed
outlist=(a b)     # outlist to be deleted from inlist

for i in "${outlist[@]}"; do
    inlist=( "${inlist[@]/$i}" )  # use outlist to remove elements from inlist
done

for i in "${!inlist[@]}"; do  # create new inlist without null elements
#   if []; then
    templist+=( "${inlist[i]}" )
#   fi
done

inlist=("${templist[@]}")
unset templist

for i in "${!inlist[@]}"; do
    echo "$i" "${inlist[i]}"
done
```

**Unexpected result**

```sh
0
1
2 c
3 d
```

**Expected result**

```sh
0 c
1 d
```

Once the array handling is working, I want to then extend the script to handle lists of files, something like

**Extension**

```sh
mapfile -t inlist < inlist.txt
mapfile -t outlist < outlist.txt

inlist.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt

outlist1.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

I am learning bash and working through some of the basic concepts around operators, expansion and substitution.

Appreciate any explanations or verbose code suggestions.

The problem seems to be the for loop not ignoring null elements when adding them to temporary array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand, where are the null elements in your input array?

Comment: Ah, I think I see, after the first loop, `inlist` is `('' '' c d)`, right?

Comment: Is the endgoal to take two input arrays and produce a third one with all the elements that are only in the first array, but not in the second?

Comment: I will add comments so it is clear. I have an array with no nulls, then delete elements resulting in a array with null elements. Then want to create a new array without null elements.

Comment: But what's the end goal? Maybe deleting the elements is part of a suboptimal approach in the first place. Like, the two lists of files, do you basically one inlist minus outlist?

Comment: (Because if that's the goal, you should have a look at `comm`.)

Comment: Yes, the goal is create inlist minus outlist (without nulls). Thank you for the `comm` suggestion, not familiar, will take a look.

Comment: It's of course perfectly fine to say you want to do it 100% in Bash to learn, but `comm` really is already solving that problem.

Comment: Excellent advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`templist` still has all the same null strings as `inlist`. You want something like

```
for i in "${inlist[@]}"; do
  if [ -n "$i" ]; then
    templist+=( "$i" )
  fi
done
```

Now `inlist=("${templist[@]}")` will reset `inlist` as desired.

You could also use

```
for i in "${!inlist[@]}"; do
  if [ -z "${inlist[i]}" ]; then
    unset "inlist[i]"
  fi
done
```

which leaves `inlist` in a slightly different state:

```
$ declare -p inlist
declare -a inlist=([2]="c" [3]="d")
```

but `inlist=("${inlist[@]}")` will ignore the actual indices when building the new array.

---

Give your two input files,

```
$ comm -23 inlist.txt outlist.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. This is another great answer and explanation, will work through it now. (also exploring the alternative approach using `comm`).

Comment: I've tried both of the `for` examples above and finding these both produce a two element array `0` and `1` as desired, but these seem to contain null elements?

Comment: I forgot to fix the first one (`-n` instead of `-z`). The second one correctly uses `-z` to unset the null entries.

Comment: Perfect `-n` on the first one did the job, checking second one.

Comment: Nice `-z` on the second one produces another state without the null indices `0` and `1` and preserves the indices `2` `3`. Interesting that suggests the indices can persist?

Comment: Yes, indexed arrays are sparse, closer to an associative array with integer-only keys rather than a proper array.

Comment: `arr=(a b c)` is a special case of the more general syntax `arr=([0]=a [1]=b [2]=c)`, where the indices don't have to be continuous or in order (though the actual indices *induce* an order in the iteration over the resulting array).

Comment: How would you create the array from the results of `comm -23 inlist.txt outlist.txt` ? or array from the results of  something like `comm -z -23 "${inlist[@]}" "${outlist[@]}"` ?

Comment: Or create the array from a `printf`, `sort` and `uniq` from something like `printf '%s\n' "${infilelist[@]}" "${xfilestring[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` or `comm` to extract elements that aren't in one list, but are in the other.

Below I `printf` the arrays as zero separated streams, `sort` them, then `comm` on them and then `readarray` into `inlist`.

```
inlist=(a b c d)
outlist=(a b)
IFS= readarray -d '' inlist < <(comm -z -23 <(printf "%s\0" "${inlist[@]}" | sort -z) <(printf "%s\0" "${outlist[@]}" | sort -z))
declare -p inlist
```

will output:

```
declare -a inlist=([0]="c" [1]="d")
```

Notes:

- this will probably be very fast
- `-z` for `comm` is a gnu extension
- you will lose the element order, as elements are sorted before `comm`.

On bash version pre 4.4 that doesn't have `-d` option with `readarray`, you can read the array line by line and append to an array:

```
inlist=(a b c d)
outlist=(a b)
while IFS= read -d '' -r a; do
    tmplist+=("$a")
done < <(comm -z -23 <(printf "%s\0" "${inlist[@]}" | sort -z) <(printf "%s\0" "${outlist[@]}" | sort -z))
declare -p tmplist
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the explanation. I will try this approach as well, just need to consider the ordering issue, would there be a way to preserve the order if this was required?

Comment: @Gabe If you know that the elements show up in both lists in the same order, then you can tell `comm` to not check if the input is ordered.

Comment: Testing `readarray -d ` or `maparray -d `and receiving `-d: invalid option`? GNU bash, version 4.3.48 installed. `readarray` on command line doesn't seem to list `-d` option. [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) lists `mapfile [-d delim]` as an option. Not sure what is happening?

Comment: Thank you. Bash 4.3 variant with the `while` loop works nicely for the `comm` and `sort` approach. Experimenting with a non-looped variant  `templist=(comm -z -23 <(printf "%s\0" "${inlist[@]}" | sort -z) <(printf "%s\0" "${outlist[@]}" | sort -z))` receives a fairly strange result and wondering why?

Comment: Reading elements in the array is delimetered with `IFS`. Default `IFS` is set to whitespace - tab, space or newline. So `templist=($( ... ))` or any variation will read array elements, but they will not be separated by null terminator, but for example by spaces or tabs, because you can't set `IFS` to zero byte. The only alternative is `readarray -d ''` or `while IFS= read -d ''`. If a newline can be a separator for your elements (there will be no newlines in your input), just drop `-z` and use `printf "%s\n"` and such.